# Batch file Error (PYTHON) - Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, batch-file, anaconda3

I have built a tkinter GUI which asks the user to select a file and then it executes python code which essentially takes a text file changes it to a csv and performs various manipulations on the data. All of this is working as it should. What I am trying to do now is have a batch file which the user will double click and the GUI will launch.

However I am getting the following error:

```
Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am very new to batch files, see my batch file below

```
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\80141219\Desktop\GUI\Select File GUI.py"
pause
```

I read online that putting the below at the top of the file might work but no luck for me, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\
```

Many thanks!!!

Comment: So you are saying it works fine from your CONDA environment?

Comment: @Squashman Yes it works just fine when I run the .py file in Spyder

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this:

```
    call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\conda activate
    "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" 
    "C:\Users\80141219\Desktop\GUI_MII_ARL\MII_ARL_GUI.py"
    @echo off
```

You need to activate conda first.
You will then run python and point to the .py file that you would like to execute.
Finally we will end with an "@echo off". The reason this is used is that the batch file was deleting itself after it ran. the echo command stops this from happening.

Comment: I was hoping my comment would lead you to that realization to activate conda.  But your comment about what `@echo off` does, is completely incorrect.

Comment: Apologies, can you please explain it's function so? It did however stop my batch file from automatically deleting

Comment: You can read the description and usage of any command by opening a command prompt and typing the command name followed by a forward slash and question mark. Example: `echo /?`. After reading that I am pretty sure you will realize that it does not do what you say it is doing.